# Getting run error even though code compiles

Tags: c

The people inside the elevator cannot press a button if their destination is adjacent to another floor. The program counts the number of people that can press a button. While the code compiles and runs correctly, the checking software used has marked my answer with a Run Error. I suspect this has to do with the memset, possibly the syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int status[20]; // stores whether a button is pressed for a floor

int main() {

    int t, n, i, j; //t is the number of cases, j is the case counter, n is the number of people choosing floors, i is the people counter

    scanf("%d", &t);

    j = 1;

    while (j <= t) {

        scanf("%d", &n);

        int cnt = 0; // counter variable to store the no of floors pressed

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int x;

            scanf("%d", &x);

            if (!status[x - 1] && !status[x + 1])
                // checks if both upper and lower floors aren't pressed
                status[x] = 1, cnt++; // sets status to 1 and increments counter

        }

        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", j, cnt);

        memset(status, 0, n * sizeof(int));

        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code may have logic errors and still compile.

Comment: Instead of `n * sizeof(int)` try `sizeof(status)`.

Comment: This is probably a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, a good time to learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash as it happen and locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: What checking software? Which "run error"? Which line of the code?

Comment: Read about comma operator, `status[x] = 1, cnt++;` you are assigning `cnt` value to `status[i]`, not 1.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider this line: `int t, n, i, j; //t is the number of cases, j is the case counter, n is the number of people choosing floors, i is the people counter`. I'd give the variables meaningful names in first place, such as `nbofcases`, `casecounter`, `nbofpeople`, `peoplecounter`. Also putting a blank line between each and every line in your program doesn't make it more readable.

Comment: "Getting run error even though code compiles": welcome to C.

Comment: After you get input from the user, and before using it as an array index, verify that it is within the valid array bounds (in this case `x>=0 && x<20`, but that could change if your array size changes...). More specifically, do not try to evaluate `status[x-1]` or `status[x+1]` if the calculated index is outside the valid range. You're going to get some form of **undefined behavior**

Answer (score 1):

If you are running traditional C, I have already spotted some simple syntax errors that will not compile in traditional C but in a C++ environment will work just fine. I don't know what your compiling this with and am simply basing it off the code that is shown on this page. Here are some corrections I would make to avoid conflicts.

Your integer values should always be declared at the top of your function call, also the **CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS** for certain scanf situations in visual studio that throw an error:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int t, n, i, j = 1; //t is the number of cases, j is the case counter, n is the number of people choosing floors, i is the people counter
    int cnt = 0; // counter variable to store the no of floors pressed
    int x;
    int status[20]; // stores whether a button is pressed for a floor

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (j <= t) {

        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            scanf("%d", &x);

            /*Checks if both upper and lower floors aren't pressed*/
            if (!status[x - 1] && !status[x + 1])
            { 
                status[x] = 1, cnt++;   // sets status to 1 and increments counter
            }
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", j, cnt);
        memset(status, 0, n * sizeof(int));
        j++;
    }
}
```

**Small disclaimer**: If you are using this code for elevator applications I am not responsible for your use of what I have **TYPED here**, this should be validated by a qualified professional before any use is made to ensure the safety of users.